# Adding Contacts to phone via JS

Tags: javascript, web, android-contacts

I have a web application that needs to add a phone number to the device's contact list. I need a way to display the android or IOS system UI prompt for adding a telephone number to the device.

Answer (score 1):

here's an intent you can launch via html / js on the Android browser:

```
intent://vnd.android.cursor.dir/raw_contact/#Intent;
    action=android.intent.action.INSERT;
    S.email=hello@world.com;
    S.phone=+1-212-555-1234
end;
```

you can launch the intent using href as a regular URL via:

```
<a href="intent://vnd.android.cursor.dir/raw_contact/#Intent;action=android.intent.action.INSERT;S.email=hello@world.com;S.phone=+1-212-555-1234end;">CLICK ME</a>
```

Sources:

1. https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data#create-an-intent
2. https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Comment: My app is not a native application but a react project.

Comment: I understand, did you try adding the "<a href=...>" tag to your html code? it should launch the add contact screen

Comment: yes. but anyway i went around it by letting my server generate a .vcf file for the user to download. but i am still open for answers though